# There is no match between the passed method name and the instance_methods of class

Tags: ruby, methods, match, instance, instance-methods

I am getting the name of a method dynamically and I am passing it for a check like this:

```
if @myObject.class.instance_methods.include?(the_passed_method_name.to_sym) then
 # Something
else
 # Some other thing
end
```

lets say that I have passed "length" or "reverse" and I make the check for the class "String" and they work perfectly fine.But when I pass "bytesize" or "gsub" it doesn't accept it in the //Something code part.It thinks that "gsub" is not part of the instance methods of "String" which is not true because when I type this in irb:

```
"String".class.instance_methods.include?("gsub".to_sym)
```

it returns **true** . Can you give an advice ?

Comment: `"String".class` is coincidentally the same as `String.class`, but `"Foo".class` is the same as `String.class` since `"Foo"` is a String.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what might be the problem, but I imagine there might be something wrong with your `@myObject`. Verify that it is actually a String object.

---

Some methods of interest that might make the code cleaner.

`method_defined?`

```
>>> String.method_defined? :gsub
true
>>> String.method_defined? :blah
false
```

`respond_to?` may be useful as well

```
myObj = "Test"

>>>myObj.class.method_defined? :gsub
true
>>>myObj.class.method_defined? :blah
false

>>>myObj.respond_to? :gsub
true
>>>myObj.respond_to? :blah
false
```

Comment: `@myObject.class.method_defined?(method_name)` should be equivalent here. `to_sym` is optional in this case.